# Restoring Outlook 2010 pst read only file

Tags: microsoft-outlook, restore, read-only, pst

I am attempting to restore an Outlook 2010 pst file from my file history, but I cannot because it is read only and I do not have permission.  I never set it as read only and it is from my old computer that crashed and died.

Answer (score 1):

You may have an permission problem here. Please read this here how on the part "To take ownership of a file or a folder" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421/en and please do the same to your pst file or you whole file system.